# How to validate model with sequelize 3.2

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to validate model but not working, here is my model:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('todo', {
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                len: [1, 200]
            }
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false
        }

    });
};
```

I can create items but validation not working.... Anyone know what is problem?